# Duplicate question when the original question has an accepted answer that doesn't answer my question

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I have a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/how-do-i-determine-which-app-is-syncing) that has already been asked and answered and that answer has been accepted, however the accepted answer doesn't answer the question.  How should this be handled?  My question is a clear duplicate however there little to no chance that I will get a sufficient answer from the original because the asker is satisfied with the only answer and has accepted it.

The best I could come up with was reopening my question and amending it to explain why the answer there didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's generally sufficient to link to the other question and explain why it doesn't meet your needs.

All we're looking for is some kind of evidence that the question asker put some effort into it, and this clearly meets that bar.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that's the current recommendation for cases like this.

Ask your question, noting the duplicate and how the accepted answer there doesn't work for you. That should keep it from being closed as a duplicate.